# Regenerate ids of existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Rails app with a custom algorithm for `id` generation for one table. Now I decided to use default incremental ids generated by Postgres as primary keys and move my custom values from `id` to another column like `uid`. And I want to regenerate values in `id` column for all records - as normal from 1 to n.
What is the best way to do this? I have about 1000 records. Records from other tables are associated with these records.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by iterating on your records, and updating them (and their associated objects). 1000 records is not that much to process.

Let's say that you have a table named "my_objects", with its model named "MyObject". Let's also say that you have another table, named "related_objects" and its model "RelatedObject"

You can iterate on all your MyObjects records, and update their related objects and the record itself at the same time.

```
records = MyObject.all #Whatever "MyObject" you have.
i = 0
records.each do |record| 
  #Updating whatever associated objects the record have
  record.related_objects.each do |related_object| 
    related_object.update_column("my_object_id", i)
  end
  #Updating the record itself
  record.update_column("id", i)
  i++
end
```

Comment: How would I handle habtm relationships? When I change primary key, they won't be updated automatically. I also think that I should wrap updates in transactions?

Comment: You can create a temporary ActiveRecord model for the middle table of your habtm association (as in a "has_many through" association), and use it to update the keys in that table, like any associated object. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: How would I delete associations for old id and recreate them for new id? `objects = record.associatied_objects.map(&:id); record.associatied_objects = []; record.save!; Object.where(id: objects).each {|o| record << o}` <- this way?

Comment: If you just change the ids coherently in all database tables, the relation will be fine. There is no need to delete and re-create relations.

Comment: What query should I use? `RelationTable.where(object_id: n).update_all(object_id: x)` ?

Comment: No, this will update all your records with the same id. You should do it for each record, like I wrote in my answer. Should I clarify my answer ?

Comment: Yes, please, that's what I'm wating for:)

Comment: I've precised that "related_objects" is the name of a model I made up for the example, 'cause I think that's what was misunderstood. Is that clearer ? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92272/discussion-between-caillou-and-leemour).

Answer (score 0):

You can keep whatever value is in ID column but create a new column named UID and set it as a primary key and auto increment

```
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE mytable modify COLUMN uid int(8) AUTO_INCREMENT"
  end
```

You can tell your model to use UID as primary key as

```
self.primary_key = 'uid'
```